# What is the critical value for those df not listed in Critical value table for Pearson correlation?

Tags: statistics, correlation, pearson-correlation, significance

What is the critical value for pearson correlation df=190? The total number of samples is 192, so df is N-2 = 190. The tables have critical values for df 100, 150, 300, 500, 1000. If the df (N-2) falls in between (e.g. 145, 395, etc., which critical value should be considered to judge whether it is significant or not.
Thanks.

Analyzed correlation between two variables, which have 192 observations in each. I could not find critical value for the df 190.

Comment: Please review what is on topic in the [help/on-topic]. Stack Overflow is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [stats.se].